# Cannot connect to Internet with USB Tethering Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, usb, ethernet, ubuntu, internet

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4, which is connected to my workstation with a usb cable. 
The goal is to be able to access the internet through the Pi4. 
I can already connect to the Pi 4 through SSH, but there is no response when pinging 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 or google.com.

What I have done so far is:

- adding `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` to cmdline.txt onto the SD card at `/boot`
- adding `dtoverlay=dwc2` to config.txt onto the SD card at `/boot`
- adding an empty file `ssh` onto the SD card at `/boot`
- setting a static ip address with with a change in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
        address 10.42.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.42.0.0
        broadcast 10.42.0.255
        gateway 10.42.0.1
```

- setting a fixed mac address `options g_ether host_addr=32:70:05:18:ff:78 dev_addr=32:70:05:18:ff:79`
- and on the host (Ubuntu 22.04) setting the connection to `Shared to other computers`
- also tried enabling ipv4 port forwarding on the host, with no success as of yet.

Websites used/guides followed:

- https://ceworkbench.wordpress.com/2019/07/09/setting-up-a-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/
- https://encomhat.com/2021/01/otg-ethernet-raspi/
- also many different SO and other forum posts

UPDATE: I have now also tried thagrols guide, with no success as of yet. Also tried configuring through DHCP.

Comment: `no response when pinging` ... pinging from where? ... Pi4 or workstation?

Comment: Pinging from inside the Pi 4.